# Is there any alternative to system() function call in jni android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Is there any alternative to `system()` function call in JNI in android as `system()` is not working while building shared library using serial communication (RS232).

My code is

```
system("ls"); //to list the files in Android Device
```

Android.mk for building sharedLibrary. Using this library(.so) I am developing an app in eclipse which is not working for me.

But `system()` returns value 11 and it's not executing the command in the quotes.

Comment: An alternative to do what - listing files in a directory? Please update your question and be a bit more precise.

Comment: Try to call some real binary from `/system/bin/` of your device? Just in case the `system()` has problem with symlinked binaries (`ls` looks to be just link to `toolbox`, at least on the device I have connected now, as I did check through `adb shell`). Also try to specify full path (`/system/bin/ls` on my current device). (`ls` itself should exit only with values 0 (OK), 1 (minor problem) or 2 (major problem)).

Comment: BTW, do you understand that thats `ls` output (list of files) will go who-knows-where (some "stdout" of VM providing JNI?), so you are probably not gonna see it anywhere? To receive it in your code, you would probably need to open some file and redirect the output of `ls` to it (never did it personally, so I can't provide any more detail).  To get list of files I would use personally normal Clib functions like `fopen`/etc...

Comment: Actually i need to know where exactly the app(.apk) will run in the device,because i am not able to run the system() method call from app by building a shared Library.where as the same cmd is working at console(At terminal).I am using ndk for building .SO and using this .so in my app.It is not working,but if i build an executable and run it in console with ./example it is working.I am not able to get the actual difference b/w them.

Comment: I need to transfer a file in the device to my PC through serial communication (RS232) not through adb .so my command to send the file is devkermit -s path of the file(/sdcard/file).It is working fine at device console,but i want to use it through my App(.apk) so i build a shared Library for it using system("devkermit -s /sdcard/file") but this is not working.Help me as it is urgent.thanks in advance